# How to Parse Json dictonary in swift 4

Tags: json, swift, json-rpc, jsondecoder

Hi I have a problem with this Json:

```
{
    "id": "libMovies",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "limits": {
            "end": 75,
            "start": 0,
            "total": 1228
        },
        "movies": [{
            "art": {
                "fanart": "myfanart",
                "poster": "myposter"
            },
            "file": "myfile",
            "label": "mylable",
            "movieid": mymovieid,
            "playcount": 0,
            "rating": myrating,
            "thumbnail": "mythumbnail"
        }]
    }
}
```

When I parse Json in swift 5 with this code

```
try! JSONDecoder().decode([MyMovie].self, from: data!)
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)):

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please **read** the error message and the JSON. It starts with a `{` so it could not be an array. And be aware that you have to decode JSON always from the top, you cannot ignore the root object.

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the below JSON,

```
{"id":"libMovies","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"limits":{"end":75,"start":0,"total":1228},"movies":[{"art":{"fanart":"myfanart","poster":"myposter"},"file":"myfile","label":"mylable","movieid":"mymovieid","playcount":0,"rating":"myrating","thumbnail":"mythumbnail"}]}}
```

The **`Codable`** models that you need to use,

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let id, jsonrpc: String
    let result: Result
}
struct Result: Decodable {
    let limits: Limits
    let movies: [Movie]
}

struct Limits: Decodable {
    let end, start, total: Int
}

struct Movie: Decodable {
    let art: Art
    let file, label, movieid: String
    let playcount: Int
    let rating, thumbnail: String
}
struct Art: Decodable {
    let fanart, poster: String
}
```

Parse the *JSON* `data` like so,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(response.result.movies.map({"file: \($0.file), label: \($0.label)"}))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Edit:**

To save the movies separately, create a variable of type [Movie],

```
var movies = [Movie]()
```

Now, while parsing save the `response.result.movies` in the above created property,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(response.result.movies.map({"file: \($0.file), label: \($0.label)"}))
    movies = response.result.movies
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: How can I print only "file", "lable" values?

Comment: Use `print(response.result.movies.map({"file: \($0.file), label: \($0.label)"}))`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, but now I want to put response.result.movies in to a "listMovie". I tried with listMovie: [Result] -> listMovie.append[response.result] but not work. I get only first value

Comment: Because you need to make your list of type `Movie` and append `response.result.movies`

Comment: I get this error " Cannot convert value of type '[Movie]' to expected argument type 'Movie' "

Comment: By making your list of type movie I meant it should be `[Movie]`

Comment: @TheCesco88 Updated the answer.